# Adding arrow segments to a scatter plot in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, arrows

I have `XY` data I want to plot in a scatter plot using `R`'s `plotly` `package`. 
For some of the points I have arrows, defined by their X and Y start and end coordinates, which I also want to plot.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),
                 arrow.x.start=NA,arrow.y.start=NA,
                 arrow.x.end=NA,arrow.y.end=NA)

arrow.idx <- sample(100,20,replace = F)

df$arrow.x.start[arrow.idx] <- df$x[arrow.idx]
df$arrow.x.end[arrow.idx] <- df$arrow.x.start[arrow.idx]+runif(length(arrow.idx),-0.5,0.5)
df$arrow.y.start[arrow.idx] <- df$y[arrow.idx]
df$arrow.y.end[arrow.idx] <- df$arrow.y.start[arrow.idx]+runif(length(arrow.idx),-0.5,0.5)
```

Using `ggplot2` this is achieved using:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+
  geom_segment(aes(x=arrow.x.start,y=arrow.y.start,xend=arrow.x.end,yend=arrow.y.end),arrow=arrow())
```

Which gives:
[image]

In `plotly` this will plot the points:

```
plotly::plot_ly(marker=list(size=5,color="black"),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=df$x,y=df$y,showlegend=F) %>%
  plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="x",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F,showgrid=F,showgrid=F),yaxis=list(title="y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F,showgrid=F,showgrid=F))
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to add the arrows.

The `add_segments` has the `x`, `xend`, `y`, and `yend` arguments and adding that:

```
plotly::plot_ly(marker=list(size=5,color="black"),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=df$x,y=df$y,showlegend=F) %>%
  plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="x",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F,showgrid=F,showgrid=F),yaxis=list(title="y",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F,showgrid=F,showgrid=F)) %>%
  plotly::add_segments(x=df$arrow.x.start,xend=df$arrow.x.end,y=df$arrow.y.start,yend=df$arrow.y.end,line=list(color="blue"))
```

Seems to add a point at the end of the line:

[image]

And I couldn't find in its documentation an argument that will add arrow head at the end of the line.

Any idea?

Comment: Seems to be ignoring the `df$xend` and `df$yend` arguments and just adding lines pointing with an arrow head to `df$x` and `df$y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use annotations

```
plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_markers(~x, ~y) %>%
  add_annotations( x = ~arrow.x.end,
                   y = ~arrow.y.end,
                   xref = "x", yref = "y",
                   axref = "x", ayref = "y",
                   text = "",
                   showarrow = T,
                   ax = ~arrow.x.start,
                   ay = ~arrow.y.start,
                   data = df[!is.na(df$arrow.x.start),])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dww. That's close. Only thing that's wrong is the location of arrow heads. They are at `arrow.x.start` and `arrow.y.start` rather than at `arrow.x.end` and `arrow.y.end`

Comment: There is an unconnected arrow on the upper right corner (not connecting any point). Why is that? Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: @CyG - well spotted.  That seems to be a weird bug in plotly.  We can fix it by adding `data = df[!is.na(df$arrow.x.start),]` to the `add_annotations`