# Segments connecting points disappear in R plotly animation

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to connect points over time using a R plotly animation.

Several issues appear with the code below:

1. The segments float from one connection to another.
2. The segments disappear from one day to another even though the connection still exists on the consecutive days (see `df`).
3. Not all connections were plotted.
4. I tried to exchange `add_segments` with `add_annotations` [to have arrows instead of segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623808/adding-arrow-segments-to-a-scatter-plot-in-plotly) but the `frame` argument would not work.

Note that removing the `color` and `symbol` arguments help with point #2 and #3.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

set.seed(12)
df <- tibble(
  day = rep(1:8, each = 10),
  id = rep(paste0("ID", 1:10), 8),
  infector = NA
) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(1),
         y = rnorm(1),
         group =  sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    infector = case_when(
      id == "ID2" & day >= 1 ~ "ID4",
      id == "ID3" & day >= 2 ~ "ID4",
      id == "ID1" & day >= 3 ~ "ID2",
      id == "ID5" & day >= 3 ~ "ID3",
      id == "ID6" & day >= 3 ~ "ID4",
      id == "ID10" & day >= 4 ~ "ID2",
      id == "ID9" & day >= 7 ~ "ID5"
    )
  )
infectors <- df %>% filter(day == 1 & id %in% .$infector) %>%
  select(id, x, y, group) %>%
  rename(infector.x = x,
         infector.y = y,
         infector_group = group)

df <- left_join(df, infectors, by = c("infector" = "id"))

pal <- c("A" = "blue", "B" = "green", "C" = "red")

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ y,
    frame = ~ day,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste("ID:", id),
    symbol = ~group,
    color = ~group,
    colors = pal
  ) %>%
  add_segments(
    x = ~infector.x,
    xend = ~x,
    y = ~infector.y,
    yend = ~y,
    color = ~infector_group,
    colors = pal,
    frame = ~day)
```

Comment: I think that what happened here, happens to all of us. You're not dropping segments. Right now there are only 4 segments to plot (days 2, 3, 4, and 5). I'm guessing that is not what you were expecting so it all comes down to inspecting what you're expecting whenever you manipulate data.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. I am expecting a "cumulative" animation where segments remain on the plot once they are drawn. If you do `df %>% filter(day == max(day)) %>% drop_na(infector)` you find that there should be a total of 7 segments at the end of the animation. However those segments should appear on the relevant day and remain for all consecutive day. I believe that df is correctly coded to do that.

Comment: Take a look a the data frame before you plot. That's not what you're getting. When I ran your code for your segments, there were only four rows.

Comment: @Kat I am sorry but I do get total of 7 segments, which also corresponds to the `case_when()` code written to reproduce `df`

Comment: To redeem myself, as I was definitely wrong, I've added a potential solution. If you want arrows instead (as you mentioned in your original question), I could probably work that out. Just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments I felt I found the mistake, you pointed out that I didn't. You're right. So, I made it my goal to answer your question to redeem myself.

##### BLUF (or my the more trendy TL;DR):

Add all lines to every frame, but change the line width, depending on which frame the segments are supposed to be visible. (Opacity was ignored, but width worked the first time.)

---

##### Lengthy Explanation

First, Plotly has pointed out there are severe limitations in their animations. Although, far better explanations exist in the Python platform. There is a trouble ticket that is several years old about issues with lines in general, as well.

However, the limitation issue here is that each point that is present in the first frame has to be present in the second. It doesn't have to be in the same place, but the quantity is very relevant. I figured this is programming and where there is a will, there is a way. After attempting to make this work through many different avenues, I think what I'll show you is probably the easiest way to make this happen.

###### Step 1

Identify all possible line segments, regardless of `frame` (or `day`).

###### Step 2

Create a list of `layout.shapes` for each segment.

###### Step 3

Create the base plot and *build* it.

###### Step 4

Iterate through the `frames` (or `day`), and find which of the unique `shapes` (line segments) exist in each frame. If `shape` is in `frame`, assign linewidth to 2 (default width). If it's not in the `frame`, assign a linewidth of close enough to zero that Plotly will still consider it 'to exist' (I used .001).

###### Step 5 *Entirely Optional*

I added a bit of code to change the legend, so it's just the single letter instead of `A<br />A`.

###### Step 6

Plot it... it's done.

```
#--------------- Step 1 ---------------
shDt <- df[, c(4:5, 7:9)] %>% na.omit() %>% # identify all possible segments 
  distinct()
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
#        x       y infector.x infector.y infector_group
#    <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>         
# 1 -0.957 -0.780      -2.00     -0.152  C             
# 2 -0.920  0.0120     -2.00     -0.152  C             
# 3 -1.48  -0.778      -0.957    -0.780  C             
# 4 -0.272 -0.703      -0.920     0.0120 B             
# 5 -0.315  1.19       -2.00     -0.152  C             
# 6  1.58  -1.29       -0.957    -0.780  C             
# 7  0.428 -0.293      -0.272    -0.703  A              

#--------------- Step 2 ---------------
shps <- invisible(lapply( # create shapes list for frame layout
  1:nrow(shDt),
  function(i) {
    list(type = "line",
         xref = "x", yref = "y",
         # dbl bkt to drop name
         line = list(color = pal[[shDt[i, ]$infector_group]]),
         # simplify = F), # to prevent linking btw frames
         x0 = shDt[i, ]$infector.x,
         x1 = shDt[i, ]$x,
         y0 = shDt[i, ]$infector.y,
         y1 = shDt[i, ]$y)
    # visible = F)
  }))

#--------------- Step 3 ---------------
plt <- plot_ly(df) %>% # base plot (markers only; as originally doc)
  add_markers(
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ y,
    frame = ~ day,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste("ID:", id),
    symbol = ~group,
    color = ~group,
    colors = pal
  )

plt <- plotly_build(plt)      # build plot

#--------------- Step 4 ---------------
# add every shape to every frame, change width
invisible(lapply(                     # by day, what segments are present?
  unique(df$day),
  function(j) {
    df2 <- df[, c(1, 4:5, 7:9)] %>% na.omit() %>% 
      filter(day == j) %>% select(-day)
    df2_ <- do.call(paste, df2)       # make row into 1 el for comparison
    shDt_ <- do.call(paste, shDt)
    keepers <- which(df2_ %in% shDt_) # get match indices
    # message(keepers)                # view segment indices by day
    shps2 <- invisible(lapply(
      1:length(shps),
      function(k) {
        if(k %in% keepers) {
          shps[[k]]$line$width <- 2      # width if present in frame
        } else {
          shps[[k]]$line$width <- .001   # width if not in frame
        }
        shps[[k]]                        # update the shape in shapes
      }
    ))
    plt$x$frames[[j]]$layout <<- list(shapes = shps2) # add to the plot
  }))

#--------------- Step 5 ---------------
# optional.... fix double chars in legend
invisible(
  lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),   # remove duplicate name in legend
    function(l) {           # only keep first letter
      plt$x$data[[l]]$name <<- substr(plt$x$data[[l]]$name, 1, 1)
    }
  )
)

#--------------- Step 6 ---------------
plt
```

[image] [image]

[image]

I guess I should point out one very odd inconsistency. When I assigned a color to the segments I used the `pal` object that you created and that is used in the `markers` portion of the plot. However, if you notice, the green segment is definitely a different shade of green. Odd.

Comment: Great work as always!

Comment: Thank you so much for your hard work and great explanation. For the colour issue I think that can be solved by using hex values e.g. #00FF00

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a complete workaround as shown by @Kat - but I'd like to provide some context which is too long for a comment.

The issue here is, that the splitting of your data into different traces via     `symbol = ~group, color = ~group` and `color = ~infector_group` does not play well with plotly's animations.

Please see this related [comment](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1696#issuecomment-898946925):

> Animations are designed to work well when each row of input is present
> across all animation frames, and when categorical values mapped to
> symbol, color and facet are constant across frames. Animations may be
> misleading or inconsistent if these constraints are not met.

In other words: animations work well if all traces exist in every frame of the animation, which is not the case for your example.

If we comment out the grouping you get the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

set.seed(12)

df <- tibble(
  day = rep(1:8, each = 10),
  id = rep(paste0("ID", 1:10), 8),
  infector = NA
) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(1),
         y = rnorm(1),
         group =  sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    infector = case_when(
      id == "ID2" & day >= 1 ~ "ID4",
      id == "ID3" & day >= 2 ~ "ID4",
      id == "ID1" & day >= 3 ~ "ID2",
      id == "ID5" & day >= 3 ~ "ID3",
      id == "ID6" & day >= 3 ~ "ID4",
      id == "ID10" & day >= 4 ~ "ID2",
      id == "ID9" & day >= 7 ~ "ID5"
    )
  )

infectors <- df %>% filter(day == 1 & id %in% .$infector) %>%
  select(id, x, y, group) %>%
  rename(infector.x = x,
         infector.y = y,
         infector_group = group)

df <- left_join(df, infectors, by = c("infector" = "id"))

pal <- c("A" = "blue", "B" = "green", "C" = "red")

plot_ly(df) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ y,
    frame = ~ day,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste("ID:", id),
    # symbol = ~group,
    # color = ~group,
    colors = pal
  ) %>%
  add_segments(
    x = ~infector.x,
    xend = ~x,
    y = ~infector.y,
    yend = ~y,
    # color = ~infector_group,
    colors = pal,
    frame = ~day) %>% animation_opts(
      frame = 500, transition = 0, easing = "linear", redraw = FALSE
    )
```

[image: result]

Regarding `add_annotations`: annotations are layout attributes not traces. It would be possible to link a relayout call to the animation steps in plotly (JS) however, currently R plotly does not allow the definition of [custom animation steps](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1719).